# Prove (or disprove) that $\log_2 n^n=O(\log_2 n!)$ and $\log_2 n!=O(\log_2 n^n)$.

Tags: limits, logarithms, asymptotics

I have to prove (or disprove) that $\log_2 n^n=O(\log_2 n!)$ and $\log_2 n!=O(\log_2 n^n)$.

I've tried to solve this by calculating $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{\log_2 n^n}{\log_2 n!} \right\rvert$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{\log_2 n!}{\log_2 n^n} \right\rvert$$ but I've had difficulty finding these limits.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you tried [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Answer (score 1):

I think one part of the question has been answered already (i.e. $\log_2 n^n \geq \log_2 (n!)$).

For the second part (i.e. to show that $\log_2 n^n = O(\log_2 n!)$), note that $n! \geq n\cdot (n-1)\cdots (n/2) \geq (n/2)^{n/2}.$ I think you should be able to finish it from here.

Answer (score 0):

- $n! =1...n \leqslant n.n....n = n^n$ so $log_2 n^n\leqslant (\log_2 n!)$, which gives : $$\log_2 n!=O(\log_2 n^n)$$
- As @stupidqnasker remarked, $n!\geqslant n.(n-1)...(n/2)\geqslant (n/2)^{n/2}$ so $\log_2 n! \geqslant n/2 \log_2 n/2 \geqslant n/3 \log_2 n = 1/3 \log_2 n^n$ for $n$ big enough. So we have that $$\log_2 n^n = O(\log_2 n!)$$

Comment: Actually $\log_2 n!  \in \Omega(\log n^n)$ though.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, I edited

Answer (score 0):

$$ \begin{split}
\left(\frac1 n \sum_{j1}^n \log_2 k\right ) -\log_2 n &= \frac1 n \sum_{j=1}^n (\log_2 k -\log_2 n)\\
&= \frac1 n \sum_{j=1}^n \log_2 \left (\frac k n \right)\\
&\rightarrow \int_0^1 \log_2 x dx=-\frac 1 {\ln 2}
\end{split}
$$

Thus $$\log_2(n!)=\log_2(n^n)-\frac 1 {\ln 2}n+o(n)\sim \log_2(n^n)$$
which proves the result.